# Create AngularJS Directive to Validate on Blur

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hoping to re-create some of the functionality that's available to us in Angular 1.3.X -- the app I am creating **has** to work well (or at least well-enough) in IE 8. For that reason, I am (sadly) constrained to not using 1.3.X. I've been running into some trouble trying to emulate the `$ng-touched` attr that is available in 1.3.X.

One part of our app needs to alert users that their form element is invalid if they've `tab`-bed through it. As it stands, it doesn't set the `$invalid` attr on any form elements unless I've entered in text and deleted it. I tried using `$pristine` and `$dirty` to achieve `$invalid` after tabbing through, but they both seem to act based on the input's value, not whether it's been touched (maybe this was one of the big advantages of 1.3.X)

**Goal**: when a user tabs through a form, validations can be fired and set each empty form element as `$invalid` if it's blank. Basically to emulate the behavior of the $ng-touched attr in 1.2.X. Here's what I have so far:

```
angular.module('goodStewardApp')
.directive('chf-validate', function () {
return {
  require: 'ngModel',
  link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
    $(elm).blur(
      function(elm) {
        ctrl.$setValidity(elm, false);
      }
    );
  }
};
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: first argument of a jQuery event handler is `event` not element

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the best way to accomplish emulating the behavior of `ng-touched` in angular 1.2.x is to use ngBlur to set a validation attribute to be true. So:

```
<form name="aForm">

   <input name="foo" ng-model="foo.bar" ng-blur="validateThisElement=true" ng-required="true">

   <div ng-show="aForm.foo.$error.required && validateThisElement"> 
      Oh no! An alert!
   </div>

</form>
```

This allows you to run a validation after a user `tab`s through your form, a common way that people used to using computers will use to interact with your angular form/app. Hope this helps anyone still stuck w/ 1.2.X for IE8 reasons!